# Compare a column between two tables and add a new column with a integer wherever they match using sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables: table1 and table2. I want to compare dx1 from table1 with code in table2, if they match I want to create a new column called 'newversion' in dersiredoutout table and populate that particular row with 9. I have tried the code below but it doesn't work :(

**Table1**:

```
version   |    dx1
----------+----------
null      |   uuu98
null      |   asdf0
null      |   mnbv9
```

**Table2**:

```
code  |   description
------+---------------
asdf0 |   tadatada
```

Desired output:

```
    version  |   dx1   | newversion
    ---------+---------+------------
    null     | uuu98   |
    null     | asdf0   |     9
    null     | mnbv9   |
```

My SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW desiredoutput AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             version, dx1, 
             CASE
                WHEN (SELECT dx1 
                      FROM table1 
                      WHERE (dx1 IN (SELECT code FROM table2)) AND version IS NULL)  
                   THEN 9
             END as newversion
         FROM 
             table1)
    )
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: @JohnConde sorry about that! could you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to display the additional NewVersion column in the output of the `SELECT` statement then

```
SELECT
    Table1.Version,
    Table1.Description,
    CASE WHEN Table2.code is NULL then NULL ELSE 9 END as NewVersion
FROM 
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.dx1 = Table2.code
```

should work for you.

Comment: I was in the middle of posting when you edited your answer to this +1.  Anyway, our queries are still not identical.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via a left join:

```
SELECT
    t1.version,
    t1.dx1,
    CASE WHEN t2.code IS NOT NULL THEN 9 END AS newversion
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.dx1 = t2.code
```

Follow the link below for a demo in MySQL (you never told us which database you are using).

## Demo

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be to compare `t2.code` column to `t1.dx1` using `case` as below.

```
SELECT t1.version,
       t1.dx1,
       CASE
           WHEN t1.dx1 = t2.code THEN 9
       END AS newversion
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.dx1 = t2.code;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RHBWXL85418)**